# Recommended regular expression editor for Mac

Tags: regex, editor

I am reading "Mastering Regular Expressions In Perl". I am using regular expressions in Java, however it would be nice if I had a editor or just something simple for Mac. (I am new to regular expressions). Another bonus would be if it was free, however any suggestions on what I could use is super.

Thank you for your time:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you have Parallels Desktop? If so, use [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com). Nothing comes close (even though it's not free).

Free and web-based: [Regexr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/), [Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/) or [Regexp Editor](http://myregexp.com/) (the latter one being implemented in Java).

Comment: +1 I agree. RegexBuddy rocks. It knows the specific dialects of all the major regex engines and can auto-generate correct code snippets to help you implement your well crafted regexex. It takes care of all the backslash-soup that occurs when copying and pasting to-from source code strings. (It even has a regex _debugger!_ - handy for checking performance tweaks.) _Highly Recommended!_

Comment: Oyster (http://www.rwe-uk.com/app/oyster)

Answer (score 3):

I usually check my regular expressions with the native search / replace box of [KomodoEdit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit). However it might be a little "heavy" for what you need.

Search engines point to [RegExr Desktop](http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/desktop/), existing for Mac as well.

Comment: RegExr Desktop I saw in a youtube video that looked clean and simply. On the site currently, looks confusing, cluttered and heavy.

Comment: This answer published 8 years might be at little outdated :)

Answer (score 2):

you could always try Rubular http://rubular.com/

Comment: [Rubular](http://tubular.com) works well but for offline, local regex syntax highlighting I found [TextMate](https://macromates.com/) to be a modern and up-to-date application. Runs well on macOS Catalina. [Vim](https://www.vim.org/) with `hl` highlight search enabled is still my favourite though.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried different editors (TextWrangler, Tincta, etc.) through AppStore, also standard TextEdit. They position themselves as Developer Tools and offer basic free version and full featured non free version.
Unfortunately free version was lacking regex and thus pretty useless as in totally useless even for non dev purposes.

But...

Textmate is the editor I'm currently using. It has all the goodies like regex search, syntax highlighting for brazillion of languages, etc.

http://macromates.com/

Smultron is also a good choice: regex support, not free in AppStore, but free on the sourceforge (of course, authors would appreciate donations for the time they put into the development):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/smultron/

Smultron was crashing for me from time to time and loosing unsaved data, so I had to look for alternatives. Maybe they fixed stability/data recovery bugs, I'll give them another look only if my current editor forces me to.

My vote goes to Textmate.